# Стандартные библиотеки LLVM C++ и GNU C++ имеют разные заголовки

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm

Мне нужны классы `unordered_map` и `tree` ([описание в GNU `libstdc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/trie_based_containers.html)), но ни одна из этих библиотек не предоставляет обеих:

```
// работает только при LLVM library
#include <unordered_map>
// работает только при GNU library
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А где вы взяли `tree` и какая структура под этим понимается? Не помню такого в стандартных библиотеках, а разных деревьев существует очень много.

Comment: Найден на сайте GCC GNU: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/trie_based_containers.html

Comment: Дык это `trie`, а не `tree`. Но это всё равно не стандартный контейнер. Вам какой нужен? Дерево поиска?

Comment: @D-side да, дерево PATRICIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unordered_map` лежит в `unordered_map`. У всех C++0x-совместимых компиляторов.

`tree` (как и `trie`, упомянутый в комментариях) не является стандартным типом и запросто может **не существовать вовсе**. Поэтому вам придётся либо **взять внешнюю реализацию (что портируемости ради предпочтительнее)** (префиксное дерево штука популярная, поищите), либо использовать компилятороспецифичные хаки, что плохо, но иногда может быть оправдано.

С помощью препроцессора и макросов можно включить некий заголовочный файл **только** в Clang (или в тех, кто им притворяется, это не очень-то надёжно):

```
#ifdef __clang__
#include <unordered_map>
#endif
```

Это не единственный способ обнаруживать Clang препроцессором, но в списке, выдаваемом `clang -dM -E -x c /dev/null` ([взято из вопроса об обнаружении Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2658461/2076787)) он выглядел наиболее подходящим.

Досыпать макросов других компиляторов, `#else` и `#elif` по вкусу.